# Best way to provide url to angular $http.get/.post

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, url, relative-path, angular-http

I am using angular with MVC4. I would like to call a MVC controller method from javascript using $http.get().  It requires a url (obviously).  I would like this to be a relative path, but how do I write that?  My controller is in Controllers/Api/ExampleController.  I would like the path to resolve even if I move the javascript file into another location, meaning I would like the path to be relative to application root as opposed to the javascript file.  I Have tried "~/Controllers/Api/ExampleControllerMethod" and "Controllers/Api/ExampleController/Method.

Comment: It would be better if you show your directory structure.
Have you tried using "/Controllers/Api/ExampleControllerMethod" ?

Comment: No I haven't tried that. The controller directory is in the root of my web application.

Comment: "/Controllers/Api/ExampleControllerMethod"  should work!

Comment: No that doesn't work - and also how would it work not knowing what controller to go to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the ideas but this kind of thing is what I was looking for:

Configure the WebApiConfig to add a route like so (should have it as default):

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ApiMethods",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

So now I can go $http.get('api/{controller}/{method}')

Comment: I was doing the mistake of having $http.get('/api/v1/...') .. The first slash was unnecessary and after changing to $http.get('api/v1/...') it worked. There was no need for $location

Answer (score 3):

The `$location` service does provide information from the url.  So, you could construct something to then make the host and port dynamic:

```
var url = $location.host() + '/Controllers/Api/ExampleControllerMethod';
```

From the documentation:

```
**url: http://www.example.com/base/path?a=b#h**
$location.protocol() = http
$location.host() = www.example.com
$location.port() = 80
$location.path() = /path
$location.search() = {"a":"b"}
$location.hash() = h
```

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to provide the Url as "/ControllerName/Action" (instead of "ControllerName/Action")